# Вопросительная фраза или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, интонация, вопрос

> *Ой, ну что ж это такое я говорю(?)!*
>   *Да что же это такое(?)!*
>   *Да как же я сразу-то не понял(?)!*

Нужны в этих восклицаниях вопросительные знаки или нет, если важен не сам вопрос, а выражение удивления, негодования, нетерпения?

Если вопросительный знак не нужен в этих случаях, есть ли ещё какие-то, близкие или не очень, но не совсем такие же ситуации, когда интонация вроде бы отчасти вопросительная, но вопросительный знак не ставится?

Answer (score 2):

Одинокий знак вопроса в таких предложениях (кроме третьего, последнего) возможен, если это действительно вопрос, проявление любопытства/любознательности.

А "выражение удивления, негодования, нетерпения" мы можем отобразить двумя способами:

— знаком восклицания и

— совмещённым знаком вопр-воскл.

[В конце предложения могут сочетаться: вопросительный и восклицательный знаки, вопросительный знак и многоточие, восклицательный знак и многоточие. Точка с другими знаками не сочетается. Сочетание знаков препинания передает взаимодействие целевой установки и эмоциональной окраски предложения: вопрос может сопровождаться негодованием, недоумением; сильное чувство может послужить причиной недоговоренности и т. п. Чаще всего такое сочетание знаков наблюдается в прямой речи для передачи ее интонации.](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=15)

*Ой, ну что ж это такое я говорю!*

*Да что же это такое!*

*Да как же я сразу-то не понял!*

И - первые два:

*Ой, ну что ж это такое я говорю?!*

*Да что же это такое?!*